# Is there a way to don't repeat this code?

Tags: javascript

I'm making a count button but the problem is because i'm repeating the same code at least 100 times what is making the code giant, is there a way to don't repeat it hundred times for different buttons?

```
$('#rcleric21').click( function() {
    counter11 = $('#rankcleric11').val();
    if (counter11 > 0) {
       counter11--;
       total[3]++;
       totalranktres--;
       $('#rankcleric11').val(counter11);
       $('.skillpoints3').val(total[3]);
    }
});
$('#rcleric22').click( function() {
     counter11 = $('#rankcleric11').val();
     if (counter11 < 5 && totalranktres <15){
         counter11++ ;
         total[3]--;
         totalranktres++;
         $('#rankcleric11').val(counter11);
         $('.skillpoints3').val(total[3]);
    }                   
});
```

Comment: one way would be to create a function

Comment: Just say "create a function" didn't help me to see how to don't repeat this code.

Comment: maybe you should consider doing some googling around and explore what it means to write a function and figure out why it might be beneficial to you?

Comment: It's unclear what exactly "the same code" is repeating. You mentioned **100** repeats, but only posted here **2** handlers.

Comment: If you have 100 repeats, the solution is *always* a loop. Maybe backed by an array of data on the differences.

Comment: OP isn't looking for a loop. He's looking for a generic method to handle 100 different possible inputs. He only posted 2 handlers because it's not expected or reasonable for him to post 100 of them. You need to abstract OP. Separate what's different from what stays the same. Then modify the function so it uses these different changes accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

You could create a function, E.g

```
function doSomething(e) {
    console.log('Do Something');
}

$('#someId').click(doSomething);
$('#someId2').click(doSomething);
```

This way you no need to repeat the code that is executed in the click callback (doSomething function). Obviously you should adapt the inner code in order to be more generic, so it do whatever you need depending the case (tough that selectors could change, etc).

If you need to perform this action over a lot of elements, should consider adding a class to it (It is no need to loop over all your elements to attach a callback).

your code should look like..

```
function doSomething(e) {
   var elem = $(e.currentTarget);
   console.log(elem);

   //Apply your logic here based on the element here.
}
$('.clickToDoSomething').click(doSomething);
```

Comment: This is a start, but it doesn't address the differing actions taken in the two functions. Function arguments would need to be passed, and they'd need to come from somewhere.

Comment: How to resolve it its primary opinion based, that is why I not added code showing how to do it, you could use tag attributes in order to use less lines of code and for clarity, no arguments needed, etc. one named function, and one event Attachment (using class approach) is a better solution than the one that you posted, but, its just an opinion. And I've always try to answer with more generic content, for future visitors, solve the OP problem without leaving an explanation for future visitors is pointless.

Comment: I agree. I wasn't sure whether HTML data attributes were an option, and I don't have time to write up that alternative at this time.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to create a named function, and you'll also need to pass in the arguments that determine outcome. Something like this:

```
function updateThings(arg1, arg2, arg3) {

    var firstComparison = eval(arg1);
    var secondComparison = eval(arg2);

    counter11 = $('#rankcleric11').val();

    if (firstComparison && secondComparison) {
        arg3 ? counter++ : counter11--;
        total[3]++;
        arg3 ? totalranktres++ : totalranktres--;
        $('#rankcleric11').val(counter11);
        $('.skillpoints3').val(total[3]);
    }
}

$('#rcleric21').click( function() {
    updateThings('counter11 > 0', true, true);
});

$('#rcleric22').click( function() {
    updateThings('counter11 < 5', 'totalranktres < 15', false);
});
```

Note that I'm not experienced with the `eval()` method and this may need adjustment to get the arguments to be processed properly.

As others have said, a common class would be better than targeting IDs. You could include the comparison strings in data attributes. That would look something like this:

```
<div class="myClickyClass" data-arg1="counter11 > 0" ...> ... </div>

$('.myClickyClass').click( function() {
    var arg1 = $(this).attr('data-arg1');
    var arg2 = $(this).attr('data-arg2');
    var arg3 = $(this).attr('data-arg3');

    updateThings(arg1, arg2, arg3);
});
```